# Localhost xampp becomes very slow when windows pc is connected to a specific wlan

Tags: router, performance, localhost, xampp

I'm running windows 10 and xampp with php8 and mysql 8 a well (the latest xampp package) and a php application.

When disconnected from a specific tplink btand new mr6400 wlan router the app runs extremely slowly. Once disconnected its back to normal speed.

Have tried several settings such as hosts file, ipv6 deactivation.. etc...

The app works fine when the PC is connected to my android hot-spot but just not the tplink router.

Would appreciate a help with this.
Regards.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly do connect to or use your application? How you measure the speed?